# How do I redirect non-existing pages in Joomla to the Home Page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I'm re-designing a plain old HTML website into a Joomla 2.5 website. The navigation of the new website has completely changed and I've been told to change it so links to any non-existing pages and be redirected to the home page. The home page for Joomla is not a index.html, but a index.php if that matters.

I have edited .htaccess files before, but I'm not an .htaccess expert in mod_write so I would need a working example. Thanks!

Comment: check this http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page

Comment: @JobinJose Thanks, but I'm having difficulty figuring out where this "restricted access" is in the error.php for Joomla 2.5 to insert the PHP code.

Comment: Rather than do that for all pages, whcih will among other things get Google really unhappy with you, use com_redirect to do permanent redirects of the old pages to the correct new pages.

Comment: @Elin Are you talking about SEO? If so, that is a good concern. There was a error.php already in this template from shape5.com and it might explain who the Redirect Manager wasn't working as expected to take domain.com/foobaz and redirect. Maybe I should use the error.php from system as the article says than using the one from shape5.com that came with the template?

Comment: @Edward Just add that line on top of the page "restricted access" means something like // No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

Comment: Yes I am, if you redirect all those urls to your homepage, that is massive duplicate content and you will be punished accordingly. If a page does not exist the proper thing is either a 404 error or a 403 permanent redirect. What you should do is a permanent redirect using com_redirect (you can import the old and new pairs via phpmyadmin).

Comment: Is com_redirect the same as the Redirect Manager?

Comment: No sure what I'm doing wrong the Redirect Manager is just going to the home page and not redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

This rule on top of your .htaccess should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ / [L]
```